# Rails finding from nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

`product.rb`

```
  class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :product_items
  end
```

`product_item.rb`

```
 class ProductItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
    has_many :prices
  end
```

`price.rb`

```
class Price < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :product_item
end
```

Now price table has a column called `otc`, it stores one-time cost for the product item and product item can have many prices.

Objective: The product has many product items but I need to find one minimum cost product item(say `default_product_item`). Need to select product item(along with otc) for a product with minimum otc from price table.

I am using ruby 3.0.1, rails 6.1.3.2, database, Postgres.

Comment: Are you looking to return the product or the product item?

Comment: Looking to get product item with minimum price.

Answer (score 2):

```
product_items = ProductItem.where(product: @product).joins(:prices).select("product_items.*", "MIN(prices.otc) as min_price").group('product_items.id').order('min_price').first
```

This should return SQL like

```
SELECT product_items.*, MIN(prices.otc) as min_price
FROM product_items
INNER JOIN 
prices
WHERE product_items.product_id = 6
ON product_items.id = prices.product_item_id
GROUP BY product_items.id
ORDER BY min_price 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Tried this but encountered the following error. Caused by PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product_items"

Comment: I solved the problem sth like this. Add relation in product.rb as has_many :prices, through: :product_items, now prices.order(:otc).first from product will give me price with minimum price and from this I get the product_item